# bash: read a file content into a variable, the content contains special characters: `*`

Tags: bash

I have a file named `content.txt`:

```
$ cat content.txt
```

output:

```
*
1
2
```

In the same directory, I have a bash file: `read.sh` to read the content of `content.txt`

```
$ cat read.sh
```

output:

```
content=`cat content.txt`
echo $content
```

As we can see there is a `*` in the `content.txt`. So, when I run `reah.sh`:

```
$ sh read.sh
```

output:

```
content.txt read.sh 1 2
```

It seems that, `*` has been parsed.

How can a get the content of `content.txt`? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the variable expands when `echo`. So just changed `read.sh` to:

```
content=`cat content.txt`
echo "$content"
```

Then I got what I want. Thanks, everyone.

#### update

http://www.shellcheck.net/ this, can check the shell script and give some suggestion.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! You may also be interested to know that [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points this out.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` character is a wildcard character for globbing that expands to file names in the current directory and must be quoted or escaped if you wish to `echo` only the character.

You can read from a file using the `read` builtin command.

```
while read content; do
    echo "$content"
done < content.txt
```